# Django - Form returning invalid due to empty form field

Tags: django

In my project, I have a Django form which consists of an **ImageField** and a **CharField**. I pass this form to my template, and display it. On the form, I set the **method** attribute to **POST**. In my view I handle this request, and return a redirect in return.

However `form.is_valid()` is returning `False` in my view, and I print the forms errors in the console.

Here is the error returned from `form.errors`:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>image<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

It is saying my **ImageField** input field is empty, however I definitely select a file for the **ImageField** in the browser, therefore I don't know the reason why it's saying that the input field is blank. My code is below.

**forms.py:**

```
    class CreatePost(forms.Form):
        // The field that is not being assigned a file 
        image = forms.ImageField(allow_empty_file=False, required=True, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'id': 'image'}))
        description = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Add a caption:', 'id': 'description'}))
```

**views.py**:

```
def create(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreatePost(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("YES")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            context['error'] = 'Please enter valid form data'
    else:
        form = CreatePost()

    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'create.html', context)
```

**Template**:

```
<form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                    {{ field }}
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
                <button class="createBtn btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post</button>
</form>
```

Does anybody know the issue here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. you need to pass *both* `request.POST` *and* `request.FILES` to the form:

   ```
   form = CreatePost(request.POST, request.FILES)
   ```
2. in order for a form to submit both files and fields, you need to specify the encoding type to `"multipart/form-data"`:

   ```
   <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ```